# Could not get test funds on stellar laboratory

Tags: stellar-laboratory, friendbot

```
{
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed",
  "title": "Transaction Failed",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html",
  "extras": {
    "envelope_xdr": "AAAAABB90WssODNIgi6BHveqzxTRmIpvAFRyVNM+Hm2GVuCcAAAAZAAABD0AA1fGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMJy1sOUpthXv7Ba6bBCm6DZZGvPMiPKWYCxpfA16mjAAAAAXSHboAAAAAAAAAAABhlbgnAAAAECjcZtcWTnpoPiAOcdJwB2ah7a3UFF0i/W+3Tmv3Uzp5+j4N2jspOnSmwn60DA7CgQYM2iMbGrPiyZWxFwe/7AM",
    "result_codes": {
      "transaction": "tx_failed",
      "operations": [
        "op_underfunded"
      ]
    },
    "result_xdr": "AAAAAAAAAGT/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA/////gAAAAA="
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Friendbot has some outages from time to time. Looks like it [ran out of money](https://stellar.expert/explorer/testnet/account/GAIH3ULLFQ4DGSECF2AR555KZ4KNDGEKN4AFI4SU2M7B43MGK3QJZNSR) this time. It usually does not take long for someone at SDF to fix it. You could follow [keybase chat](https://keybase.io/team/stellar.public) to stay up to date about this kind of issues.

It is best practice to create only one account with friendbot (on testnet reset) and consecutive test accounts from that one on your own.

Comment: Also after your first account funding, you could issue your own asset and have large amounts of asset to test with. No need to do it all in XLM.